# Parse site with json data (part2)

Tags: asp.net, json, parsing

i parse successfull the site i want but i can t keep this data because after 30mins the link i take is not valid anymore. Can anybody explain me what happens and how can i fix this?
My Code is :

```
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.Headers.Add("Referer", "http://sletat.ru/");//MUST BE THIS HEADER
        string result = wc.DownloadString("http://module.sletat.ru/Main.svc/GetTours?cityFromId=832&countryId=35&cities=3106&meals=&stars=&hotels=&s_adults=1&s_kids=0&s_kids_ages=&s_nightsMin=6&s_nightsMax=16&s_priceMin=0&s_priceMax=&currencyAlias=EUR&s_departFrom=26%2F06%2F2012&s_departTo=19%2F07%2F2012&visibleOperators=&s_hotelIsNotInStop=true&s_hasTickets=true&s_ticketsIncluded=true&debug=0&filter=0&f_to_id=&requestId=19446078&pageSize=20&pageNumber=1&updateResult=1&includeDescriptions=1&includeOilTaxesAndVisa=1&userId=&jskey=1&callback=_jqjsp&_1340728614816=");
        result = result.Substring(result.IndexOf("{"), result.LastIndexOf("}") - result.IndexOf("{") + 1);
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        dynamic json = js.DeserializeObject(result);
        var prices = json["GetToursResult"]["Data"]["aaData"] as object[];
        // var operators = ((object[])json["result"]["prices"]).Cast<Dictionary<string, object>>();
        var temp = prices.ToList().Take(20).Select(x => new TableRow
        {
            Operator = (x as object[])[18].ToString(),

        }).ToList();
        string str = "";

        foreach (var tableRow in temp)
        {
            str += tableRow.Operator + "<br />";
        }
        Response.Write(str);
```

Thanks in advise

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the parts of the link that keep changing are values generated on server which change on each request.
You could get the data you want not in a single step but in several steps such as:

1. Perform a request to main page `http://sletat.ru`
2. Parse the response from step 1. In the response markup you'll find the parts of the link that is changing on each new request.
3. Use that data to create your request and send it to the server.